# Is there a unicode capable alternative for word boundary escape sequence "\b"?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, word-boundary

I'm interested in a Unicode capable alternative for the JavaScript word boundary escape sequence "\b". The problem with \b is it's limited to ASCII characters which fails for words like "Münster". 
I am not looking for a universal valid-for-all-languages solution. I just target Latin based languages (e.g. English, German, French, ... etc). I wonder if there is something which builds on Unicode character categories ([see here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm))

Comment: No, there is not, and it can't be emulated with regular expression alone.

Comment: Have you tried [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and there is no equivalent to the \b. Better alternatives for \w and \W exist, but not \b